# How to import D3 package before another script/ package which requires D3?

Tags: angular, d3.js

I have a package which requires `D3`. I am importing `D3` package before the another package but still throws error.

```
import 'd3';
import 'daily-weather-graph-d3';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  graph;
  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.graph = new DailyWeatherGraph({
      data: data,
      container: document.getElementById('graph'),
      width: 880,
      height: 440
    });
  }
}
```

`daily-weather-graph-d3` package is using `D3`.

Error:

> Error: d3 is not defined

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-historical-graph)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an issue on imported dependency. I've modified a few things and now it's working fine[image], pls refer the link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-charts-admusa

Comment: Could you please tell me what you did to fix this so I implement it on my project? Thanks

Comment: First of all I’ve structured your code, and then I just reinstall d3 js & daily-weather-graph-d3. I found issues on your code, you have defined graph data outside of ngoninit & defined const variable outside constructor. After fixing its start working for me. Pls refer the stackblitz link that I’ve shared for more help.

Comment: Looks like you fix this by adding `d3.v4.min.js` dependency. How you added this? I mean through which command? I am adding `d3` with `d3`.

Comment: Yes I’ve also added this d3.v4.min.js library. You can add this directly from CDN, here is the link https://cdnjs.com/libraries/d3. Select any version and add it using script tag directly. Hope it will help:)